# Unexpected error processing reply from import status service

Tags: jss

I have Sitecore 9.3 version and followed the steps described here https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install to setup JSS server. I am not able to deploy the app while running deploy command, I am receiving the error

```
Unexpected error processing reply from import status service:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at C:\jss\jss-app\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\package-deploy.js:238:42 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

This issue can happen due to incompatible version of JSS app with sitecore version. Can you verify what version you have used when creating your jss app?

For sitecore 9.3 you need to create jss app using release/13.0.0 by this syntax: `jss create appname react -b release/13.0.0`. You can verify the JSS module compatibility with the sitecore version on the page https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788

Comment: Thanks @Cristi Vulturar, only your comment has help me.

Comment: Indeed this is the fix. I am running sitecore version 10 and the JSS app version was 16.0. i too got the same issue and created a new app with jss create appname angular  -b release/15.0.0 fixed the issue. i.e compatible JSS version

Comment: So @Kanniyappan Krishnan, can we mark this as the right answer? Have you tested?

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same error for Sitecore 10.x version. I have followed the below steps to resolve the error:

1. Uninstall npm Sitecore JSS in the global and local path(where your code placed)

```
   npm uninstall -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
   npm uninstall -i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
```

2. Again install the Sitecore JSS package.

```
   npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@16.0.0
   npm install -i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@16.0.0
```

The version mentioned should match with the installed packages Sitecore Headless Services Server for *Sitecore 10.1.0 XM 16.0.0 rev. 210223.zip*.

Answer (score 1):

I faced many issues and struggled about 3-4 days, now I just realised.
To avoid Jss app deployment issues, make sure `jss-sitecore-cli` and `jss server module` have the same version.

For this purpose execute below command with specific version. e.g. you have installed "Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 10.0.0 XP **15.0.1** rev. 201112.zip" package for Sitecore 10.0.1.

```
npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@15.0.1
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Thanks,
Akif

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure both your global jss cli version and the jss cli version in your project's package.json match!

I had this same error:
[Error running `jss deploy app`: TypeError: logReplies.forEach is not a function](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28285/error-running-jss-deploy-app-typeerror-logreplies-foreach-is-not-a-function)