# JSS deploy items ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

When trying to deploy a newly generated `JSS` App to the new `Sitecore` server, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Unexpected error processing reply from import status service:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined TypeError:
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

This question has been posted before, [[Unexpected error processing reply from import status service]](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28055/unexpected-error-processing-reply-from-import-status-service), but none of the answers resolved the problem:

- I've generated new apps with and without the `--branch release/19.0.0`
- I've uninstalled the `Sitecore-JSS-CLI` node module and reinstalled to get the latest version `19.0.2`
- Double-checked settings in `scjssconfig.json` and `\sitecore\config\app-name.config`.

**Current Version Information**

```
Sitecore version: Sitecore.NET 10.2.0 (rev. 006766)  
jss --version: 19.02
```

I've added a `console.log` statement to `package-deploy.js` to give me more information about the error from the import service on the Sitecore server:

```
>Job started: JSSImport-sbxa-test-i-4:57:17 PM,#Exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown 
by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.***Zip***, Version=12.2.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The 
system cannot find the file specified.  
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.ImportService.ImportJob.StartImportInternal()  
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I find it curious that the `JSS` import service is trying to reference an assembly contained in a ***.Zip*** file.

I can't find anything in the Sitecore logs, nor am I sure which log to review for JSS import errors.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, it’s a version mismatch, fixed this on our end by creating an app in a compatible JSS version. In this case, ours is 9.3, so we created the matching JSS version i.e 13.0.0

```
jss create my-first-jss-app react -b release/13.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a version mismatch issue, I face same issue with Sitecore 10.2 version, checked if you have installed correct version with Sitecore 10.2 then it will start working

> https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering/19x/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering_1900.aspx

I installed above version to make it working. if not then installed older version and installed compatible version with 10.2

hope it will help you.